# csh: Every command returns "no match"

Tags: macos, tcsh, csh

I'm on mac OSX mountain lion working with csh. I'm not quite sure what I did, but suddenly every standard unix command I run returns a "no match".

Example:

```
$ echo "Hello"
echo: no match
$ rm a.txt
rm: No match
```

I guess it's time to switch to bash, but anyone have any idea what might cause this?

Comment: What is your `PATH`? What happens when you start `tcsh` without loading startup files?

Comment: Have you recently defined any new aliases or made other changes to your `.cshrc` or `.login` files?

Comment: could be a bug in some autoexecuting code, eg a prompt the executes something on every command.   Try starting a new shell with /bin/csh -f to surpress startup file loading.